# New IDLE won't let me move left-right for long lines

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I'm very fond of IDLE and an older version that came with Python 2.7.1.1 on my old macOS computer allows me to slide the text left-right so I can read long lines (comments or some script lines).

My new IDLE on my new macOS computer installed from python.org (with the trackpad set up the same way I believe) balks, and

1. moves the text vertically when I move left-right on the trackpad
2. moves the text vertically *a lot* when I resize the window horizontally from the right edge.

`Python 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020, 12:11:27)` and `Tk version 8.6.8`

Is this a "new feature" of IDLE, or perhaps something is not setup right? The behavior seems counterintuitive.

**note:** The IDLE that runs when I type "idle" in a command window that was presumably installed with anaconda acts perfectly normal, i.e. lets me move left-right. But it [freezes my terminal regularly](https://superuser.com/q/1572849/390541) so I don't use it often.

`Python 2.7.16 (default, Jun  5 2020, 22:59:21)` and `Tcl/Tk (8.5.9)`

**note:** in both cases I just use IDLE as an editor, I run using Anaconda 3 from command line terminal.

macOS two fingers sliding left-right moves the text horizontally:

[image: macOS two fingers on trackpad to move text horizontally]

Comment: As for 3.8.5: I have 3.9.0rc1 installed, which has the same code.  I can move the insertion (edit) cursor left and right, including to see the end of long lines, with Left and Right arrow key, and with Command-Right/Left.  Moving the mouse cursor (with short horizontal lines) with either mouse or trackpad does not move text.  So I have trouble visualizing what you see.  But it does not sound normal or like any intended change.

Comment: As I explained in answer to the linked superuser question, one should not use tkinter on Mac with the ancient, buggy, crash or freeze prone tcl/tk 8.5.9 still supplied with Apple.  Current PSF python.org Mac installers include a recent tcl/tk.  Windows installers have always done this.

Comment: For me, two fingers instead of one, together or apart, cancels the one finger mouse movement, resulting in no movement of anything.  This must be a macOS configuration somewhere.  Except for looking at IDLE behavior, I am not a mac user, so know nothing about such things.  In any case, IDLE does not track mouse (or trackpad) movements.  Consider opening an issue on bugs.python.org, where our macOS experts can comment.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy thanks for your suggestion. I'm not sure what "IDLE does not track mouse (or trackpad) movements" means exactly since it really does scroll up-down based on trackpad movements and does *or at least did* scroll left-right via trackpad movements as shown in the GIF above.

Comment: Today I can move text up-down with 2 fingers within about an inch of each other moving up down (or left-right) with enough pressure to register but not click.  (And I discovered that both click == Right click.)  I can imagine that left right should move text left-right instead.  I expect that same will be true with pure tkinter program (no IDLE code) and will test later.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy wow thank you for pursuing this!

Answer (score 1):

It does the same thing to me (on Windows 10). What version of the IDLE are you using?
I think that it is a new feature. Anyway, you can see the text that you write with the keyboard arrows. Please, provide the version of Python that you are using

Comment: I've updated the question with the two versions, and was surprised to see one is 2.7 for some reason! I just use IDLE to edit, I run them separately from a command window using the Python 3 Anaconda installation.

Comment: I am an IDLE maintainer, using Windows 10, and I have no idea what either of you are seeing or what you think might be a new feature.  Moving the mouse cursor should not and for me does not change the displayed text on Windows or Mac unless I hold down the left mouse button to select text.  In both cases, IDLE is not involved as the text and mouse are managed by tk and the text widget.  Perhaps one of you can give more details.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy thanks for your reply! I've added GIF to the question illustrating what I've always been able to do in macOS until recently. For the case where an IDLE editing window is say 80 characters long and there is text that for whatever reason is 100 characters long, I want to move the text *sideways*  so that the left (beginning) 20 characters disappear beyond the left edge of the window and the right (ending) 20 characters appear on the right side However in the newest IDLE the two finger horizontal slide and horizontal resize of window moves the text *vertically!* totally unexpected.